# Изменить многоточие text-overflow: ellipsis на свой текст

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть "статьи", которые обрезаются с помощью text-overflow: ellipsis, для их раскрытия используется многоточие.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно заменить его на свой текст (например, Подробнее ^, синим цветом)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю, что стандартными средствами с этим не справиться и нужен плагин, а в какую сторону смотреть не знаю.

Нашел только как можно эти три точки стилизовать, но не как изменить содержимое. Например,  text-overflow: '...'; но это совсем не то

Также попробовал сделать как в этой статье с помощью js, но не смог придумать как сделать его в виде ссылки, как атрибут a, и оно работает в js fiddle, но не работает у меня в приложении

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549021/text-overflow-change-content-of-ellipsis

Comment: Для начала, `text-overflow: ellipsis` в принципе не работает как то, что на "получившимся" скриншоте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий прототип:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".drop-text").forEach(el => {
  const button = el.querySelector('.drop-button');
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    el.classList.toggle("closed");
    button.textContent = el.classList.contains('closed') ? 'Развернуть' : 'Свернуть';
  });
});
```

```css
.drop-text {
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(242, 112, 156), rgb(255, 148, 114));
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.drop-text div {
  word-break: break-word;
}

.drop-text.closed {
  height: 150px;
}

.drop-text .drop-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-text closed">
  <h2>Какой-то текст</h2>
  <div>Какой-нибудь случайный длинный текст для демонтрации работы виджета и его функционала и вообщеафвфцщшвлф зшвцофшзщвоцфщцшзво зщцвофшзцвозшфволфвош зшфовщфцвщгрфщцгврфзшарфцвзшгр фгвризыфшгаифзШГВИФАШЗФЗШАВФМИАШЗНМФЦЗАНФыхщуарыфхщовфщшцохшфцвadadawdadawdadadwawdadawd
  </div>
  <button class="drop-button">Развернуть</button>
</div>
<div class="drop-text closed">
  <h2>Какой-то текст</h2>
  <div>Какой-нибудь случайный длинный текст для демонтрации работы виджета и его функционала и вообщеафвфцщшвлф зшвцофшзщвоцфщцшзво зщцвофшзцвозшфволфвош зшфовщфцвщгрфщцгврфзшарфцвзшгр фгвризыфшгаифзШГВИФАШЗФЗШАВФМИАШЗНМФЦЗАНФыхщуарыфхщовфщшцохшфцвadadawdadawdadadwawdadawd
  </div>
  <button class="drop-button">Развернуть</button>
</div>
<div class="drop-text closed">
  <h2>Какой-то текст</h2>
  <div>Какой-нибудь случайный длинный текст для демонтрации работы виджета и его функционала и вообщеафвфцщшвлф зшвцофшзщвоцфщцшзво зщцвофшзцвозшфволфвош зшфовщфцвщгрфщцгврфзшарфцвзшгр фгвризыфшгаифзШГВИФАШЗФЗШАВФМИАШЗНМФЦЗАНФыхщуарыфхщовфщшцохшфцвadadawdadawdadadwawdadawd
  </div>
  <button class="drop-button">Развернуть</button>
</div>
```

Сейчас изменил на гораздо более короткий вариант, который к тому же работает для нескольких карточек, за вами стили)

Comment: Спасибо большое, похоже на то, что я искал. Попробую применить завтра, обязательно отпишу, если сработает, останется только придать кнопке хороший вид

Comment: @Revasha, на самом деле если карточек больше, чем одна, то не сработает. Чуть позже изменю ответ, добавлю в него вариант для нескольких карточек.

Comment: @Revasha, изменил ответ

Comment: @Voprositel: а что будет, если текста вдруг будет мало и/или он будет полностью виден? Кнопка всё равно будет присутствовать? Тогда теряется весь смысл задумки. Раз уж используете JS, то нужно сделать проверку для таких случаев, иначе это простой спойлер, который реализуется на чистом CSS.

Comment: Спасибо. Пришлось немного поколдовать, чтобы это все впихнуть. За обновленную версию очень благодарен
Проверка на длину и правда не помешает, но это пока не моя забота. Если что, попробую разобраться сам или задам вопроос